# Posting special characters with non-UTF-8 page results differently between IE and Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, internet-explorer

I have a form in a page with this meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5">
...
<form action="/myurl" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

While posting the form using Chrome, requests with special characters ,for example "É", was encoded to `&#201;`, while posting "É" using IE encodes the character to `&Eacute;`

Chrome encodes it to numeric html entity while IE encodes it to named html entity.

Due to some reason I can't change the charset of the page. I would like to know if there is a way to send requests with same result (named/numeric html entity) crossing browsers.

versions of browsers:
Chrome: 87.0.4280.88
IE: 11.0.9600.19356

Comment: How do you encode the request data? I use C# and I encode it in the backend using [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=net-5.0#System_Web_HttpUtility_HtmlEncode_System_String_). The results are `&#201;` in both Chrome and IE. You can also try to use this method if you're using C#.

Comment: I didn't encode them. It's a normal htm webpage generated by php, And the request data automatically encoded by browsers while submitting the form.

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but I think you need to encode it by yourself. I find this function [`htmlentities`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and you can have a try. I use [this page](https://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder) to test and it has the same result when encode in IE and Chrome.